# How can I make a copy of a file removing all whitespace (so the new file has no whitespace)

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to delete all the spaces from a given file and write the result to another. I want to use a shell script for this.

Comment: What would be the difference between a direct command and a shell script?

Comment: vertical whitespace (double newlines? single newlines?) or only horizontal whitespace? (spaces and tabs). Please don't write comments in the answer section...

Answer (score 4):

To remove all *horizontal* whitespace characters (i.e. spaces and horizontal tabs)

```
tr -d '[:blank:]' < file > newfile
```

To remove *all* whitespace characters (including newlines and vertical tabs)

```
tr -d '[:space:]' < file > newfile
```

Note this will leave the file without its POSIX-mandated terminating linebreak: see for example [Why should text files end with a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/4440445)

Answer (score 3):

Text-processing with a shell is slow. You should use a text processing utility for that. For example, you could use `sed`

Remove all horizontal whitespace:

```
sed 's/\s//g' file > output
```

Remove all horizontal whitespace and empty lines or lines with only whitespace:

```
sed 's/\s//g;/^$/d' file > output
```

Remove all whitespace of any kind relentlessly, including all newlines

```
sed ':a;s/\s//g;N;s/\n//;ba' file > output
```

#### Notes:

- `s/\s//g` replace any horizontal whitespace character with nothing, matching every whitespace character on the line (`g` means all matches on the line)
- `;` separates `sed` commands
- `/^$/` empty line
- `d` delete the pattern space
- `:a` label - execute from here
- `N` read the next line into the pattern space
- `\n` newline in the pattern space
- `ba` branch to label `:a` and execute again

Comment: I know its slow with  shell, i want in that, plzz.

Comment: @AbhishekChourasia ok, but I don't know how to do it with only Bash. Stack Exchange answers are not only for the asker, but for the whole community. This answer is for others who don't insist on making the shell do things that perfectly good text processing software has been written to do faster and more easily ;)